# Coded UI C#: Adding dynamic date to datatable

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm doing the coded ui test for a website that is displaying data per section:

For example:

Section 1: displays link 1, link 2, link 3

Section 2: displays link 3, link 5, link 6

I want to verify that the website is displaying data correctly as above so I decided to add initial data in csv file with format as below: (note: It's just a example, the content of each link is different with others)

Section 1,link 1

Section 1,link 2

Section 1,link 3

Section 2,link 4

Section 2,link 5

Section 3,link 6

Then, I load the data from csv file to datatable and compare each row in datatable with the real data in the website.

That works perfect until i found some links contain some dynamic date (some contain today date, some contain previous date, they change frequently)

I was thinking about the solution that add some variables to the csv file and insert the date to it.

For example I add the variables to csv as below:

Section 1,link 1 **{0}**

Section 1,link 2 **{1}**

Section 1,link 3 **{2}**

Section 2,link 4

Section 2,link 5

Section 3,link 6

And replace them with the real date but i don't know how.

Below the code i use to load data from csv file to datatable:

```
public System.Data.DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string pathFile)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathFile))
            {
                string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(header);
                }
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dr[i] = rows[i];
                    }

                    if (rows.Length != headers.Length)
                    {
                        for (int i = headers.Length; i < rows.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dr[headers.Length - 1] = dr[headers.Length - 1] + "," + rows[i];
                        }
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

            }
            return dt;
        }

DataTable table = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(projectPath);
```

Please help me on it. Thanks

Comment: What date do you want to insert? Today? Yesterday? Ten days from today? What language are you using your Coded UI tests? Where do you want to insert the date? Please [edit] the question to include a lot more details of what you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you, @AdrianHHH, i changed my question. do you have any solution?

Comment: you are dynamically adding rows and columns already. there's not much difference between adding a text column or a date column.

Comment: Could you please specific on that? I want to add dynamic data at the end of text in a column as example above. Something like using **String.Format("this is test {0}, 8/1/2018)** => the output should be **"This is test 8/1/218"**

Comment: My first comment above asked *"what date do you want to insert?"* You have not answered that and I think that that is your problem. You want to insert a date but do not know what that date is. When you explain what date is to be inserted it may be easier to answer your question. Secondly, which column or columns do you want to add the date to? How do you choose which columns are to have the date added?

Comment: Hi @AdrianHHH, i think that what date is not important. For example, i want to add today to row 1, col 3 at the end of the text string, and add previous day to row 2, col 3 at the end of the text string (Please refer to the example). Your question "How do you choose which columns are to have the date added?" is actually the problem that i am facing. I don't know how to add a date (or some texts) to the row and col that i want to add. Thanks

Comment: I have tried really hard to understand your question and to get you to explain what you want. I am unable to help any more until you put some real effort into writing a clear question.

Comment: Hi @AdrianHHH,  I rewrite the question. Please help me review and let me know where is not clear for you so i can explain more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the loop containing `dr[i] = rows[i];` to be.

```
int drIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
    dr[drIndex] = rows[i];
    drIndex++;

    if (i == indexForInsertingTheDate)
    {
        dr[drIndex] = theDateToBeInserted;
        drIndex++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you might alter the loop body from the simple `dr[i] = rows[i];` to be:

```
string field = rows[i];
if (field.StartsWith("this is test "))
{
    field += theDateToBeInserted;
}
dr[i] = field;
```

The question does not specify what date to use. If today's date is needed then you can set `theDateToBeInserted` to `DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH for the answer, actually, I use the method "ConvertCSVtoDataTable" to convert some csv files, and few of them don't need to insert a date. And also the text does not start with "this is test", its just the example. Does there any way to modify the data after converting to Datatable instead. Thanks

Comment: @user1710727, please edit your question to show what you really want. It seems like you just need some simple code to be written, but your question is not at all clear about what you have, what you want, what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Ok @AdrianHHH, I edited the question. Please take a look if you have time. Thanks